# How to change the orientation for a single view not for all views in ipad?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios7, uiinterfaceorientation

I am fresher to IOS. In my iPad application i have 6 views are there. By default i fixed the orientation to Landscape mode for all screens. But my 5th view has to change like Portrait mode when i open that particular one, Is there any programatic code to change that particular view orientation? Would you please help me in this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which iOS version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

1.You need to generate DeviceOrientation notification by invoking

```
-(void)beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications
```

method of `UIDevice`.

2.in UIViewController which control your view add notification observation

```
[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(rotateMyUIView:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

3.in `rotateMyUIView` metod rotate your UIView using

```
myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2); // you must check orientation first
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` in that specific view-controller which you didn't want to get affected.

Answer (score 0):

After the iOS 6 you can do it like this..

In AppDelegate.h file

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    BOOL allowRotation;
}
```

In AppDelegate.m file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    allowRotation = NO;  
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(changeDeviceOrientation:) name:@"ChangeDeviceOrientation" object:nil];

    return YES;
}

- (void) changeDeviceOrientation:(NSNotification*)notification {
   if(allowRotation)
   {
       allowRotation = NO;
   }else
   {
       allowRotation = YES;
   }
}

-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    NSLog(@"Not FullScreen");
    if (allowRotation) {
        NSLog(@"FullScreen");
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

And in your viewcontroller(Which viewC you want to change orientation) call this notification

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ChangeDeviceOrientation"   object:nil];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ChangeDeviceOrientation"   object:nil];
}
```

Comment: As per your code, from application stating onwards all screens showing Portrait mode only. But my requirement is, all 5 screen should be in landscape mode except that particular screen. When application starts the first screen should be in Landscape, if i enter into 5th screen, automatically it has to change to portrait mode thats the problem.